# Not able to retrieve datas from Short dynamic link - Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-invites

When I create dynamic links which contain UTM parameters and share it, I was able to retrieve the data and encoded queries from the link. But when I try to create a short link of a dynamic link using firebase recommended method, I can only able to retrieve the path, but not the encoded queries. how do I solve it?

METHOD FOR CREATING DYNAMIC LINK :

```
public void buildReferral() {
    DynamicLink dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse("sample link"))
            .setDynamicLinkDomain("sample domain")
            .setAndroidParameters(
                    new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("com.package.my")
                            .build())
            .setGoogleAnalyticsParameters(
                    new DynamicLink.GoogleAnalyticsParameters.Builder()
                            .setSource("referral")
                            .setContent("content")
                            .setMedium("Android")
                            .build())
            .buildDynamicLink();
    buildShortUrl(dynamicLink);
}
```

METHOD FOR CREATING SHORT LINK :

```
 public void buildShortUrl(DynamicLink dynamicLink) {
    Task<ShortDynamicLink> shortLinkTask = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLongLink(Uri.parse(dynamicLink.getUri().toString()))
            .buildShortDynamicLink()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ShortDynamicLink> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Short link created
                        Uri shortLink = task.getResult().getShortLink();
                        Uri flowchartLink = task.getResult().getPreviewLink();
                    } else {
                        // Error
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: How are you sharing the shortened link?  Passing it to `AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder().setDeepLink()`?

Comment: Intent intent  = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder("Share via")
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.referral_text))
                .setDeepLink(shortLinkUri)
                .setCallToActionText("Install")
                .build();
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);                                                                     this is how the short link is shared. @BobSnyder

Comment: My experience has been that AppInvite shortens the link you pass to `setDeepLink()`.  I don't think there is any value in you shortening it before passing to `setDeepLink()`.  I am able to send a long link with params, see the short link received, and extract the params from the URI in the received dynamic link data.

Comment: I was not able to invite users via WhatsApp using firebase invites. hence I thought of shortening the link and sharing it via Intent normally to WhatsApp. Is there a way to share links to WhatsApp using firebase?

Comment: I don't know about WhatsApp.  I would guess that you could shorten the link as you are doing and embed it in a text message.  In my app, if the user wants to send a dynamic link using Firebase Invites, I send the long link.  Or the user can share the link using SMS or email.  For those cases, I shorten the link as you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `appendQueryParameter()` to add multiple parameters to the link, and by using `getQueryParameter()` you can retrieve parameters from link. You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50341159/firebase-dynamic-links-failing-to-fetch-parameter/50342925#50342925) answer how you can achieve it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to get the parameters passed here, not which I pass using appendQuery()  -  
                    .setGoogleAnalyticsParameters(
                    new DynamicLink.GoogleAnalyticsParameters.Builder()
                            .setSource("referral")
                            .setContent("content")
                            .setMedium("Android")
                            .build())